# Login form validation in codeigniter not working

Tags: codeigniter

Login form validation not working for me.It works fine for signup but when I tried same thing with my login form.Some checks not working properly in code igniter.
here is my code.I run code ,it goes in my else condition but don't show validation error.
First two checks creating problem for me.When input empty or some enter wrong format of email.

```
function index() {
    $data['nav']= $this->category_model->view_brands();

    if($_POST) {
        $data['error'] = '';
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_login', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_login', 'Password', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {
            $log_in = $this->login_model->login_beyond(
                        $this->input->post('email_login'),
                        md5($_POST['password_login'])
                      );

            if($log_in !== FALSE) {
                echo "<script>window.location.href=\"../index.php\"</script>";
            } 
            else {
                // Set your error message
                $data['error'] = 'Wrong Username/Password';
            }
        } 
        else {
            // Set the validation errors
            echo "it came heere but donot show errors"; 
            $data['error'] =validation_errors();
        }
    }

    $data['login_not'] = "login";
    $this->template->load('template','client/login_view',$data);
}
```

Comment: add your view code also

Comment: what error is displaying

Comment: it shows nothing...But it comes in else condition.As i echo above it..But error do not come.It shows same form.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to write `if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)` and work from there instead of writing `if($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE)`. This is because in form validation, when `run()` return true, it may be because it evaluated all results and **did not find** any errors or the values given did not even exist so error validation did not apply on non-existing values.

Lemme know if it works